# How can I write javascript functions in content page html and how I call that function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I write two javascript functions in content page. Then I take a html textbox and on the onkeypress event I try to call those two functions, but I am running that application and I didn't find any output to help me. 
Here I am trying to count number of characters in textbox on keypress event. If I write a javascript function in simple page then it runs successfully but it doesn't run in content page help me.

Here is the code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile ="~/Site1.Master"  CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" 
    contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">

    <script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript">
    maxL=0;
 var bName = navigator.appName;

    function taCount(taObj,Cnt,totmsg) 
    { 
        objCnt=createObject(Cnt);
        objtotmsg = createObject(totmsg);
        objVal=taObj.value;
        if (objCnt) 
        {
            if(bName == "Netscape")
            {   
                //objCnt.textContent = maxL-objVal.length;}
                var totalchar = parseInt((objVal.length - 1) / 160);
                objCnt.textContent = maxL + objVal.length;
                objtotmsg.textContent = totalchar + 1;
            }
            //else{objCnt.innerText= maxL -objVal.length;}
            else
            {
                var totalchar = parseInt((objVal.length - 1) / 160);
                objCnt.innerText= maxL + objVal.length;
                objtotmsg.innerText = totalchar + 1;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    function createObject(objId) 
    {
        if (document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(objId);
        else if (document.layers) return eval("document." + objId);
        else if (document.all) return eval("document.all." + objId);
        else return eval("document." + objId);
    }

    </script> 
<textarea id="TextArea1" onkeyup="return taCount(this,'charcount','totalmsg')" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>

    <asp:Label ID="charcount" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>/<asp:Label ID="totalmsg" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Accept the answer, since you also bothered to leave a comment saying it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the IDs get lengthened (their naming containers are pre-pended) when inside a master page, so instead of this:

```
taCount(this,'charcount','totalmsg')
```

You'll need this, which gets their actual rendered IDs:

```
taCount(this,'<%=charcount.ClientID %>','<%=totalmsg.ClientID %>')
```

If you view source in the browser and search for `charcount` or `totalmsg` when rendered in that master page, you'll see what I mean about the IDs, they'll probably look something like this: `_ctl00_Content1_charcount`.

Comment: thank you for solve my prob
could we make good frnd
just give me your mail id 
thank for solve my prob again

Comment: @Neo - There's no need :) Welcome to SO, you can thank me and help the next guy by using the check-mark to the left to accept this answer...you should do this to whichever answer best helps solve the problem on each of your questions.